# Remote webservice over ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, webserver

Want to access remote webserver. The setup is like this:

LinuxDesk  --> jumpuser@sshserver --> sshuser@webserver

Above all of them are linux servers. web service is running on 8080 port.
How to access webservice from desktop by creating ssh tunnel.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: From Linux desktop browser, I want to access the service running on webserver. There is a jump server in between. Webserver IP is not directly accessible from Linux desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up two tunnels:

- (simple or reverse) `LinuxDesk:port1 -> sshserver:port2` - the port numbers don't have to be 8080
- (simple or reverse) `sshserver:port2 -> webserver:8080`

You'd then end up with the service at your LinuxDesk at the port `port1`.

Probably you want a reverse tunnel to the webserver and also a reverse one to the sshserver, but possibly not.

For implementation see `man ssh`. Just look there for "tunnel".

Comment: How to access the service from the browser? Is it localhost:8080 or something else?

Comment: @Thunder It will be at `localhost:8080` if you tunnel like `localhost:8080 -> sshserver:port2` in the `LinuxDesktop`. I'm not sure if it will be also available there if you tunnel your outgoing interface, eg. `192.168.0.x`. You can check, but you can simply use `localhost`.